# Emphasize multiple parts within a single string

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

How do you emphasize multiple parts within a single string with reStructuredText using Sphinx?

I have the following line:

```
*foo*.*bar*.*spam*
```

And I want to get the following HTML generated:

```html
<p><em>foo</em>.<em>bar</em>.<em>spam</em></p>
```

However, Sphinx is generating:

```html
<p><em>foo</em>.*bar*.*spam*</p>
```

I've also tried doing:

```
*foo*\ .*bar*\ .*spam*
```

But that just results in the same output.

NOTE: I'm running Sphinx 1.3.1 with Python 2.7.

---

To emphasize each part individually I had to do:

```
*foo*\ .\ *bar*\ .\ *spam*
```